# outlook add-in is not working outlook desktop client using react js

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Outlook add-in is not working on the outlook desktop client  us the error
SCRIPT5022: Office.js has not fully loaded. Your app must call "Office.onReady()" as part of it's loading sequence (or set the "Office.initialize" function). If your app has this functionality, try reloading this page.

Comment: From your comments below, your add-in is working fine for your Desktop Outlook client, however, it is not working on Microsoft 365 16.0.13901.20436 on Windows 10.0.18362.1411. Which version of Outlook do you have? And if your version is much lower than the one it is failing on, are you able to upgrade? Please provide your Windows version as well to help us determine which underlying browser Outlook is using to run the add-in.

Comment: Predictable Behavior

1100.4.4.2  O365 Perpetual
Your offer is not working on Microsoft 365 on Windows, Outlook 16.0.13929.20296

The add-in does not load

Reproduction Steps

Launch the add-in on Outlook
Observe the blank Taskpane UI display
See "blank.mp4 & load.mp4" for reference.

Please update the offer to be fully functional in all required environments and resubmit your offer.
this was the error given by microsoft patner center

Comment: But same verison is working fine for me . so how i can resolve they give rejection on their side cz its was not working on windows server

Comment: For clarifications around certification results, a ticket should be raised here https://aka.ms/marketplacepublishersupport as is advised in the rejection report. We cannot discuss individual offer results on offers forums.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the Internet Explorer version. It is hard to give the definitive answer when we don't know where exactly an add-in is launched.

Office Add-in cannot successfully call any Office JavaScript APIs until the library has been loaded. [Initialize your Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/initialize-add-in) article describes the two ways your code can ensure that the library has been loaded:

- Initialize with `Office.onReady()`.
- Initialize with `Office.initialize`.

Make sure you have defined any of them in your add-in.

Comment: /* Render application after Office initializes */
Office.initialize = () => {
    isOfficeInitialized = true;
    render(App);
};
i'm using Office.initialize method in react app as you can see .

Comment: Your offer is not working on Microsoft 365 16.0.13901.20436 on Windows 10.0.18362.1411.
Your add-in loads blank in above configuration.
To reproduce this issue:
Launch the add-in
Observe no content loads in task pane.
Please refer to the attached video (blank.mp4)
Please update the offer to be fully functional in all required environments and resubmit your offer. this was rejection I'm facing because Office.js has not fully loaded but its working fine for my window desktop client .